# volume of the solid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Using geometry, calculate the volume of the solid under $z = \sqrt{49- x^2- y^2}$ and over the circular disk  $x^2+ y^2\leq49$.

I am really confused for finding the limits of integration. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You said using geometry, not calculus, so integration should not be required.  Can you figure out what the shape is?  You might try a different coordinate system.

Comment: alright, but still i am not getting any right answer

Comment: If you square the first equation, what does it look like?  Then the under means you will be considering $\le$ instead of $=$

Comment: I am still confused could you write the solution way

Comment: What does $x^2+y^2+z^2=49$ look like?

Comment: i am not sure, I really appreciate your help but could you be straight forward with me please

Comment: It is a sphere of radius $7$

Comment: ohh you are right, but i still can not get it please show me the way of the solution

Comment: So what part of the sphere are we concerned with?

Comment: the base part of the sphere, right ?

Comment: Where is the center of the sphere?  What is the $z$ coordinate of the disk?  Where does it cut the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you are using double integration, by considering an elementary area $dxdy\space$ on the X-Y plane, the elementary volume (dV) of solid can be given as
$$dV=zdxdy$$
$$V=\iint zdxdy$$ Since the surface $z=\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}\space$ intersecting the disk $x^2+y^2\leq49 \space$ in the XY plane hence the limits can be applied as follows
$$V=\int_{-7}^7\int_{-\sqrt{49-y^2}}^{\sqrt{49-y^2}}\sqrt{49-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$
Further, I guess that you can change the order of integration for simplification